# pass callback as argument to jq filter function

Tags: function, callback, jq

Is it possible to pass filter to jq filter function?

Like

```js
def something:
   [. | ..];

def something_else(callback):
    callback | map(.some_key);


something_else(something)
```

Comment: What are you expecting this to *do*?

Comment: Yes, and it works exactly like that. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/M4TwujAGh5d)

Comment: Arguments to functions are always a "callback" already and are not passed by value. For examples, the `map/1` and `select/1` functions are precisely that. You pass a "function" to do the parts necessary for it to work.